# Using wget to download files that match extensions and specific text in the filename

Tags: linux, wget

I can backup specific files with a **bmp** and **avi** extension from a site using **wget**

**Example code below:**

```
wget --tries=3 --retry-on-http-error=429,503,504 -r -l 1 -A bmp,avi -nd -H --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" https://www.site.com
```

How can I get all the files that match the extension **avi** and **bmp** but have the text **567a** in the filename?

**Example:**

The following files are found on the site **177adf-567a-u.avi** and **123adf-567a7u.bmp** those are the only files I want to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html):

> -A acclist
>
> Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or
> patterns to accept or reject. Note that if any of the
> wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of
> acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather
> than a suffix.  In this case, you have to enclose the pattern
> into quotes to prevent your shell from expanding it, like in
> -A "*.mp3" or -A '*.mp3'.

So you need to change the `bmp,avi` by a pattern. Something like this:

```
wget --tries=3 --retry-on-http-error=429,503,504 -r -l 1 -A 123adf*bmp,123adf*avi -nd -H --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" https://www.site.com
```